# Android MediaPlayer delayed surface draw causes video to be out of sync

Tags: android, video, streaming, overlay, media-player

I'm streaming video to my Motorola Droid 1 using the method from the android tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html). I'm getting different behavior from the two different formats I'd like to play. The first type (youtube lq 3gp) plays fine. The second type (youtube hq mp4) will start to play the audio before the TIOverlay functions are run (so no video), then once the video is drawn it's out of sync with the audio. I know the hq mp4 format is supported by my phone because it is the type played by the mobile youtube site which works fine. More info on the formats [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs).

So I guess I either need a way to force the TIOverlay to run, or a way to listen for it to be ready and not to start the video until that point. Some logcat output below shows the flow, it's interesting when onPrepared() is called in both cases. The 3gp seems to do TIOverlay calls before and after onPrepared(), while the mp4 only does them after.

Edit: The same code seems to be working on a Motorola Droid 3. Still, if that video format works on youtube on my Droid 1, I feel like it should work in my app as well.
I tried waiting to play the video until it was buffered a little bit. Not only did this not solve the problem, but the buffer also restarted upon starting the video.

3GP:

```
10-25 16:56:26.750: DEBUG/TIOverlay(1103): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=176 h=144 format=22
10-25 16:56:26.946: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=480 h=854
10-25 16:56:26.946: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=176 h=144
10-25 16:56:26.946: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=176 h=144
10-25 16:56:26.961: INFO/Overlay(1103): 8 buffers allocated 4 requested
10-25 16:56:26.961: INFO/Overlay(1103): buffer cookie is 2
10-25 16:56:26.961: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Opened video1/fd=138/obj=003a2160/shm=135/size=4096
10-25 16:56:26.961: DEBUG/TIOverlay(1103): overlay_createOverlay: OUT
10-25 16:56:26.961: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Nothing to do!
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=0
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=1
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=2
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=3
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=4
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=5
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=6
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=7
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=0
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/0/addr=4140a000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=1
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/1/addr=41417000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=2
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/2/addr=41424000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=3
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/3/addr=41431000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=4
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/4/addr=4143e000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=5
10-25 16:56:26.969: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/5/addr=4144b000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:26.977: DEBUG/TI_Video_Decoder(1014): VIDDEC_SendCommand: Received request from omx client to change state to 2
10-25 16:56:26.985: DEBUG/TI_Video_Decoder(1014): Handle request for state transition: 1 => OMX_StateIdle
10-25 16:56:26.985: DEBUG/d(2220): videosizechanged()
10-25 16:56:27.102: DEBUG/TI_Video_Decoder(1014): OMX_StateIdle state reached
10-25 16:56:27.305: INFO/PlayerDriver(1014): buffering (15)
10-25 16:56:28.235: DEBUG/TI_Video_Decoder(1014): VIDDEC_SendCommand: Received request from omx client to change state to 3
10-25 16:56:28.243: WARN/MediaPlayer(2220): info/warning (1, 44)
10-25 16:56:28.258: INFO/MediaPlayer(2220): Info (1,44)
10-25 16:56:28.258: DEBUG/d(2220): onPrepared()
10-25 16:56:28.282: VERBOSE/BufferAllocOmap34xx(1014): BufferAllocOmap34xx::removeRef()
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=176 h=144
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=176 h=144
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=176 h=144
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): 8 buffers allocated 4 requested
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): buffer cookie is 2
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=0
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=1
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=2
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=3
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=4
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=5
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=6
10-25 16:56:28.290: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=7
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Postponing Stream Enable/1/0
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=0
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/0/addr=4140a000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=1
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/1/addr=41417000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=2
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/2/addr=41424000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=3
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/3/addr=41431000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=4
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/4/addr=4143e000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=5
10-25 16:56:28.297: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/5/addr=4144b000/len=53248
10-25 16:56:28.891: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2050): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2271 objects / 138840 bytes in 229ms
10-25 16:56:28.966: INFO/PlayerDriver(1014): buffering (15)
10-25 16:56:29.930: WARN/MediaPlayer(2220): info/warning (1, 44)
10-25 16:56:30.258: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Position/X0/Y0/W0/H0
10-25 16:56:30.258: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Adjusted Position/X0/Y200/W480/H0
10-25 16:56:30.258: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Rotation/0
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_set_position:: w=480 h=854
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_set_position:: w=480 h=392
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): dumping driver state:
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): output pixfmt:
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): w: 176
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): h: 144
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): color: 7
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): UYVY
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay window:
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): window l: 0 
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): window t: 200 
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): window w: 480 
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): window h: 392
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): output crop:
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop l: 0 
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop t: 0 
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop w: 176 
10-25 16:56:30.266: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop h: 144
10-25 16:56:30.274: DEBUG/d(2220): surfaceChanged()
10-25 16:56:30.297: DEBUG/d(2220): videosizechanged()
```

MP4:

```
10-25 16:51:57.454: DEBUG/d(2071): onPrepared()
10-25 16:51:58.360: DEBUG/d(2071): surfaceChanged()
10-25 16:52:02.219: DEBUG/TIOverlay(1103): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=640 h=360 format=22
10-25 16:52:02.219: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=480 h=854
10-25 16:52:02.219: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=640 h=360
10-25 16:52:02.219: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_init:: w=640 h=360
10-25 16:52:02.243: INFO/Overlay(1103): 8 buffers allocated 4 requested
10-25 16:52:02.243: INFO/Overlay(1103): buffer cookie is 2
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Opened video1/fd=139/obj=00501e18/shm=108/size=4096
10-25 16:52:02.250: DEBUG/TIOverlay(1103): overlay_createOverlay: OUT
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Position/X0/Y0/W0/H0
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Adjusted Position/X0/Y200/W480/H0
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Rotation/0
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_set_position:: w=480 h=854
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay_set_position:: w=480 h=270
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): dumping driver state:
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): output pixfmt:
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): w: 640
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): h: 360
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): color: 7
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): UYVY
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): v4l2_overlay window:
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): window l: 0 
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): window t: 200 
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): window w: 480 
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): window h: 270
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): output crop:
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop l: 0 
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop t: 0 
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop w: 640 
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/Overlay(1103): crop h: 360
10-25 16:52:02.250: INFO/TIOverlay(1103): Postponing Stream Enable/1/0
10-25 16:52:02.266: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=0
10-25 16:52:02.266: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=1
10-25 16:52:02.266: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=2
10-25 16:52:02.266: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=3
10-25 16:52:02.266: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=4
10-25 16:52:02.274: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=5
10-25 16:52:02.274: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=6
10-25 16:52:02.274: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=7
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=0
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/0/addr=420f1000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=1
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/1/addr=4269d000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=2
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/2/addr=4270e000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=3
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/3/addr=4277f000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=4
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/4/addr=427f0000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=5
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/5/addr=42861000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=6
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/6/addr=428d2000/len=462848
10-25 16:52:02.282: INFO/Overlay(1014): query buffer, mem=1 type=2 index=7
10-25 16:52:02.289: INFO/TIOverlay(1014): Buffer/7/addr=42943000/len=462848
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem. My approach was to see if it worked in its simplest form (copied the [example code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) on the android site), and sure enough it did. I then slowly built it up to the apps current functionality and it still works. Unfortunately I couldn't determine the exact cause, although in my first implementation I didn't use the exact code from the android site as the base. It seems many things can cause this problem, including doing a seekTo before starting the video, to name just one. Anyone else experiencing the "audio but no video" bug, I recommend taking this approach of starting from its simplest implementation and working back up.